# MongoDB shell script using projection to format date and get local time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

Here is the projection I am using

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ProjectID" : 999 } },
    { "$sort": { "CreatedDate": -1 } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "DueDate": {
                "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M", 
                    "date": "$DueDate"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

My due date value in Mongo is `ISODate("2016-10-08T17:00:00.000Z")` which in local time is `22:30 PM` but using above projection I get the value as 5:00 PM

this `ISODate("2016-10-08T17:00:00.000Z").toLocaleString()` returns `Saturday, October 08, 2016 22:30:00`

So how can I apply `toLocaleString()` in projection and get the result in the above format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly use "toLocaleString()". However, you can add the offset.

1) Third pipeline is used to add the offset

2) Fourth pipeline is used to format the date

```
var tzOffset = 5.5 * 1000 * 60 * 60;

db.MyCollection.aggregate( [
   { "$match": { "ProjectID" : 999 } },
   { "$sort": { "CreatedDate": -1 } },
   {          
      $project: {
         localTime: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                   "localTime": { "$add": [ "$DueDate", tzOffset]

                }
               },
               in: { $add: ["$$localTime"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {          
      $project: {
         "_id": 0, 
         "formattedLocalTime": {
                "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M", 
                    "date": "$localTime"
                }
            }
      }
   }

]);
```

**Input:-**

```
"DueDate" : ISODate("2016-08-11T10:17:09.203Z")
"DueDate" : ISODate("2016-08-11T23:16:09.203Z")
```

**Output:-**

```
"formattedLocalTime" : "2016-08-11 15-47"
"formattedLocalTime" : "2016-08-12 04-46"
```

**Please note the output 2. The next date is populated correctly.**

Comment: The above output is in 24 hour clock. So, it doesn't require AM or PM.

Comment: Apparently, there is no specifiers in dateToString to get the time output in 12 hours clock. May I request you to accept the answer if it resolved the original problem?