# $dayOfWeek and timezone in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo aggregation.

The local timezone is **EST (UTC -5)**, and the time is `08/15/16 23:00 Monday`,

In database, it is UTC time `ISODate("2016-08-16T04:00:00.000Z")`, which is Tuesday.

When I use this MongoDB aggregation:

```
Product.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: {
      day: { $dayOfWeek: '$time' }
    }
  }}
])
```

This time will be added to Tuesday. Is there a way to let it be added to Monday? Thanks

(The client side can send a timezone offset `-5` parameter to server)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890417/mongodb-shell-script-using-projection-to-format-date-and-get-local-time), it may help.

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript use the following code:

```
//you get the timezone

var timeZone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
```

send the variable to the api and use it in mongo

for example:

```
//utc-5

db.orders.aggregate(
    [
     { $group: { _id: {
         "$dayOfWeek":{$add:['$time', -timeZone]}

     }, total: { $sum: "$subTotal" } } }
    ]
)
```

Note: Subtract or add the timeZone according to the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Product.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: {
      day: { $dayOfWeek: { $add: [ "$time", 
                                { $subtract: [ new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ), new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000" ) ] } // Time Offset 
                                ] } }
    }
  }}
])
```